# Find the trig value of -x given the trig value of x

Tags: trigonometry

While studying trig functions I came across the following problem:

> Use the given value to evaluate each function 
> 2 ) $\cos{-t} = -\frac{1}{5}$; Evaluate $\cos{t}, \sec{t}$

I know that the value of $t$ is not in my table. I also know that $t$ must be somewhere in quadrants 2 & 3, since its cosine is negative. Using that information, I reasoned that $\cos{-x}$ must be somewhere in quadrants 1 & 4, so would be positive, but my textbook states that $\cos{t}=\cos{-t}$, disproving my conclusion. Why is this?

Comment: You make a confusion between $\cos(-x)$ and $-\cos(x)$.

Comment: Are you sure that if $t$  lies in $2^{nd}$ or $3^{rd}$ quadrant $\Rightarrow$ $(-t)$ lies in  $1^{st}$ or $4^{th}$ quadrant?

Take $t = 120 \rightarrow$ lies in $2^{nd}$quadrant, $-t = -120$ lies in $3^{rd}$quadrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\cos(t) = \cos(-t)$ because it is the $x$ value on the unit circle. Then, $\cos(t) = \cos(-t) = -\frac{1}{5}$, and $\sec(t) = \frac{1}{\cos (t)} = -5$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: I see. I failed to consider that $-t$ = $2\pi - t$, so the position of $-t$ on the unit circle will have the same $x$ value.